# Which database is performance oriented, MySQL or MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, database, database-tuning, mariadb

Which database is performance oriented, MySQL or MariaDB?

Which storage engine is better for all of the following?

- databases that should be scalable
- fast in query processing
- have community support
- have a lot of tutorials or any other alternatives present?

Answer (score 5):

The performance is much more dependent on the chosen database engine for MariaDB or MySQL.
MariaDB provides support for a faster write cache enabled engine called "Aria" compared to the default [MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM) Engine of MySQL.

> Aria is usually faster for temporary tables when compared to MyISAM because Aria caches row data in memory and normally doesn't have to write the temporary rows to disk.

Another enhanced area is the way of fetching a view. MariaDB usesTableElimination, but I'm not sure if MySQL uses that at all (I never found that mentioned anywhere!).

In addition to MariaDB, the same Table elimination is found in both Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008 and Oracle 11g.

Comment: Is there any alternative open source databases found with optimised performance?

Comment: It is very tough to mention anything in particular and depends on several factors as per your need e.g. Read-Optimized or Write-Optimized, which further are dependents of Level of Isolation, Locking Mechanism etc.